# Which signal emitted when the user changes the theme in layer tree using pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis

Which signal is emitted when the user changes the theme in layer tree using pyqgis.
Using QgsMapCanvas.themeChanged doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:** Use the [`mapThemeChanged`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapThemeCollection.html#ae14ec8f88ffeecd30860bd3cfc81e2fe) signal.

**Explanation:**

The theme of the map canvas is not the same as the map themes that can be selected in the layer tree.
Therefore the `themeChanged` signal you mentioned does not provide the expected results.

This implementation might not be ideal by QGIS and a bit confusing. But essentially there seems to be a *map canvas theme* and the *map themes*. These are different things.
See the following link for a brief explanation: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/27499#issuecomment-495892950

The map themes which can be applied in the layertree are stored in [`QgsMapThemeCollection`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapThemeCollection.html).
This class also provides a signal which can be used to listen for theme changes:

```py
map_themes = QgsProject.instance().mapThemeCollection()
map_themes.mapThemeChanged.connect(lambda t: print('theme changed'))
```